# LINQ without Include returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-identity

Why LINQ without `Inlcude` returns null for reference to another model?

**Models**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public FilePath FilePath { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

}

public class FilePath
{
    public int FilePathId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public FileType FileType { get; set; }
}

public enum FileType
{
    Avatar = 1, 
    Photo = 2,
    Study = 3
}
```

**Controller**

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    //...

    ApplicationUser appUser1 = db.Users.Find(id);
    ApplicationUser appUser2 = db.Users.Include(i => i.FilePath).SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
    if(appUser1.FilePath == null); //null
    if(appUser2.FilePath == null); //not null, has all data
    return View(appUser2);
}
```

Comment: What would you expect it to return if you *don't* use `.Include`?  Why would it not be null?

Comment: @KirkWoll So I have to use Include for *every* reference that I add in my model?

Comment: Or use a `.Select` projection.  Or enable [lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#lazy).  (I strongly advise you not use lazy loading in a production scenario, as it can cause startingly inefficient database activity when used in loops.)

Comment: @KirkWoll It means that references will not be automatically picked up until I explicitly ask LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mark your `FilePath` property as `virtual` to make lazy load to work:

```
public virtual FilePath FilePath { get; set; }
```

**BTW:** You question should be changed to 'Entity Framework without Include returns null'.

**Entity Framework != LINQ**. LINQ is a higher level concept, while Entity Framework just implements a LINQ provider so you can query database using linq syntax.